# google analytics - view report for recorded outbound links

Tags: google-analytics

I have added the code as listed on this page (http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1136920) to record outbound links in google analytics.

How do I view this report in google analytics, do I need to create a report?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the event tracking was set up correctly, you should be able to see your events in Standard Reporting -> Content -> Events. It can take up to 24 hours for first values to show up though.

Answer (score 5):

In the latest version of Analytics, it looks like this is now:

- Reporting > Behavior > Events > Overview

or

- Reporting > Real-Time > Events

Comment: Do you know where it is in the latest analytics?

Comment: I think it's still in the same place: click "Reporting" link at the top, then Behaviour > Events > Overview in the tree on the left.